# Error on openning Jupyter qtconsole of existing notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, qtconsole

I can open an independent qtconsole from terminal without any problem

```
$ jupyter qtconsole
```

However, when I run Jupyter qtconsole linked to an existing notebook in local, it gives errors and opens a disabled qtconsole with a blank page.

```
$ jupyter qtconsole --existing
```

or

```
$ jupyter qtconsole --existing kernel-e73a6873-0080-4bd5-9433-3ekk5c52b5c3.json
```

The error is:

```
ERROR:tornado.general:Uncaught exception in ZMQStream callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bilgen/anaconda3/envs/ml_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 556, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bilgen/anaconda3/envs/ml_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyter_client/threaded.py", line 121, in _handle_recv
    msg_list = self.ioloop._asyncio_event_loop.run_until_complete(get_msg(future_msg))
  File "/home/bilgen/anaconda3/envs/ml_env/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 623, in run_until_complete
    self._check_running()
  File "/home/bilgen/anaconda3/envs/ml_env/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 585, in _check_running
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running
ERROR:tornado.general:Uncaught exception in zmqstream callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bilgen/anaconda3/envs/ml_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 577, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/home/bilgen/anaconda3/envs/ml_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 606, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/home/bilgen/anaconda3/envs/ml_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 556, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bilgen/anaconda3/envs/ml_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyter_client/threaded.py", line 121, in _handle_recv
    msg_list = self.ioloop._asyncio_event_loop.run_until_complete(get_msg(future_msg))
  File "/home/bilgen/anaconda3/envs/ml_env/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 623, in run_until_complete
    self._check_running()
  File "/home/bilgen/anaconda3/envs/ml_env/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 585, in _check_running
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running
ERROR:asyncio:Exception in callback BaseAsyncIOLoop._handle_events(24, 1)
handle: <Handle BaseAsyncIOLoop._handle_events(24, 1)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bilgen/anaconda3/envs/ml_env/lib/python3.9/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "/home/bilgen/anaconda3/envs/ml_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 189, in _handle_events
    handler_func(fileobj, events)
  File "/home/bilgen/anaconda3/envs/ml_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 577, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/home/bilgen/anaconda3/envs/ml_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 606, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/home/bilgen/anaconda3/envs/ml_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 556, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bilgen/anaconda3/envs/ml_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyter_client/threaded.py", line 121, in _handle_recv
    msg_list = self.ioloop._asyncio_event_loop.run_until_complete(get_msg(future_msg))
  File "/home/bilgen/anaconda3/envs/ml_env/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 623, in run_until_complete
    self._check_running()
  File "/home/bilgen/anaconda3/envs/ml_env/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 585, in _check_running
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running
ERROR:tornado.general:Uncaught exception in ZMQStream callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bilgen/anaconda3/envs/ml_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 556, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bilgen/anaconda3/envs/ml_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyter_client/threaded.py", line 121, in _handle_recv
    msg_list = self.ioloop._asyncio_event_loop.run_until_complete(get_msg(future_msg))
  File "/home/bilgen/anaconda3/envs/ml_env/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 623, in run_until_complete
    self._check_running()
  File "/home/bilgen/anaconda3/envs/ml_env/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 585, in _check_running
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running
ERROR:tornado.general:Uncaught exception in zmqstream callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bilgen/anaconda3/envs/ml_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 577, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/home/bilgen/anaconda3/envs/ml_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 606, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/home/bilgen/anaconda3/envs/ml_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 556, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bilgen/anaconda3/envs/ml_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyter_client/threaded.py", line 121, in _handle_recv
    msg_list = self.ioloop._asyncio_event_loop.run_until_complete(get_msg(future_msg))
  File "/home/bilgen/anaconda3/envs/ml_env/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 623, in run_until_complete
    self._check_running()
  File "/home/bilgen/anaconda3/envs/ml_env/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 585, in _check_running
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running
ERROR:asyncio:Exception in callback BaseAsyncIOLoop._handle_events(22, 1)
handle: <Handle BaseAsyncIOLoop._handle_events(22, 1)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bilgen/anaconda3/envs/ml_env/lib/python3.9/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "/home/bilgen/anaconda3/envs/ml_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 189, in _handle_events
    handler_func(fileobj, events)
  File "/home/bilgen/anaconda3/envs/ml_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 577, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/home/bilgen/anaconda3/envs/ml_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 606, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/home/bilgen/anaconda3/envs/ml_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 556, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bilgen/anaconda3/envs/ml_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyter_client/threaded.py", line 121, in _handle_recv
    msg_list = self.ioloop._asyncio_event_loop.run_until_complete(get_msg(future_msg))
  File "/home/bilgen/anaconda3/envs/ml_env/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 623, in run_until_complete
    self._check_running()
  File "/home/bilgen/anaconda3/envs/ml_env/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 585, in _check_running
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running
/home/bilgen/anaconda3/envs/ml_env/lib/python3.9/functools.py:834: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'get_msg' was never awaited
  impl = registry[cls]
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

I couldn't find a solution.

Specs:

The Ubuntu version is,

```
$ lsb_release -a
```

> ```
> No LSB modules are available.
> Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
> Description:  Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
> Release:  20.04
> Codename: focal
> ```

The Jupyter Notebook version is,

```
$ pip show notebook
```

> ```
> Name: notebook
> Version: 6.4.12
> Summary: A web-based notebook environment for interactive computing
> Home-page: http://jupyter.org
> Author: Jupyter Development Team
> Author-email: jupyter@googlegroups.com
> License: BSD
> Location: /home/bilgen/anaconda3/envs/ml_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages
> Requires: argon2-cffi, ipykernel, ipython-genutils, jinja2, jupyter-client, jupyter-core, nbconvert, nbformat, nest-asyncio, prometheus-client, pyzmq, Send2Trash, terminado, tornado, traitlets
> Required-by:
> ```

The qtconsole version is,

```
$ pip show qtconsole
```

> ```
> Name: qtconsole
> Version: 5.3.1
> Summary: Jupyter Qt console
> Home-page: http://jupyter.org
> Author: Jupyter Development Team
> Author-email: jupyter@googlegroups.com
> License: BSD
> Requires: ipykernel, ipython-genutils, jupyter-client, jupyter core, pygments, pyzmq, qtpy, traitlets
> Required-by:
> ```